# Set Logstash Date Filter from current date to last 3 days

Tags: elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

I have Complete database in one index and daily bases i need to create or fetch 3 days records and store in CSV Format. Target is daily it take 3 days back records and store in CSV File. How To set start from Current date to Last 3 Days using only logstash.config?

### My Logstash Config File

```
input {
elasticsearch {
     hosts => "**Endpoint URL**"
     index => "**Index NAME**"
     user => "***"
     password => "***"
     query => '{ "query": { "query_string": { "query": "*" } } }'
    }
}
filter {
csv {
separator => ","
autodetect_column_names => true
autogenerate_column_names => true
}
}  
output {
     stdout {  
     codec => json_lines
            }
     csv {
     fields => []
     path => "C:/ELK_csv/**cvs_File_Name**.csv"     
  }
  }
```

---

Need To Add date filter range

```
{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"range":{"createddate":{"gte":"","lt":""}}}],"must_not":[],"should":[]}},"from":0,"size":5000,"sort":[],"aggs":{}}
```

gte start from current date and lt to last 3 days.

Answer (score 0):

Working Logstash.config File Code

```
input {
elasticsearch {
     hosts => "**ELK ENDPOINT URL**"
     index => "**INDEX NAME**"
     user => "***"
     password => "***"
     query => '{ "query":{"bool":{"must":[{"range":{"createddate":{"gt":"now-3d/d","lte":"now/d"}}}],"must_not":[],"should":[]}},"from":0,"size":10000,"sort":[],"aggs":{} }'
    }
}
filter {
csv {
separator => ","
autodetect_column_names => true
autogenerate_column_names => true
}
}  
output {
     stdout {  
     codec => json_lines
            }
     csv {
     fields => [**FIELDS NAMES**]
     path => "C:/ELK6.4.2/logstash-6.4.2/bin/tmp/**CSV_3days**.csv"     
  }
  }
```